# How do I request multiple locations simultaneously with Google's findPlaceFromQuery?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working to put many pins on a Google Map.  I cannot seem to figure out if it is possible to query for multiple locations in the same request.

I've successfully gotten my script to find a single address.

```
    var request = {
      query: address,
      fields: ['name', 'geometry']
    };

    service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, function(results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          map: map,
          title: 'test'
        })
      } else {
        console.log('ADDRESS NOT FOUND');
      }
    });
```

I have a list of addresses in an array extracted from the DOM....

```
["1749 W Peterson Ave Chicago, Illinois(IL), 60660", "1516 W Ardmore Ave Chicago, IL 60660", "1518 W Ardmore Ave Chicago, IL 60660", "1520 W Ardmore Ave Chicago, IL 60660", "1410 W Ardmore Ave Chicago, IL 60660", "1500 W Granville Ave Chicago, IL 60660", "1502 W Granville Ave Chicago, IL 60660", "1320 W Granville Ave Chicago, IL 60660", "1312 W Granville Ave Chicago, IL 60660", "1307 W Granville Ave Chicago, IL 60660"]
```

I could just run the previous code 10 times, however, eventually I'm going to be grabbing 100 or so at a time. Is it possible to send google a list of queries to be processes and returned together?

Comment: No, that is not supported by Google's APIs.

Comment: Good to know thank you